# Select statement to check multiple rows against 2 variables

Tags: sql, select, asp-classic

I have the following table :

```
alertID inspectorID datelive                dateread
1       none       2012-11-06 10:36:03.350  NULL
2       none       2012-11-06 10:36:25.043  NULL
3       none       2012-11-06 10:36:42.433  NULL
1       31030      2012-11-06 10:37:19.193  2012-06-11 10:34:47.000
```

I want to select the alerts that dont have the inspectors ID against it AND where the alert ID doesn't match the one that has the inspectorID against it, ie inspector has read alert 1 so i only want it to return alerts 2 & 3

Am using Classic ASP and MS-SQL

Comment: balls, table looked fine till i posted it

Comment: No worries I fixed it. You'll see it in a bit

Comment: Thanks for that Panagiotis :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Select * From Alerts
Where AlertId Not In (Select AlertID From Alerts Where InspectorID IS NOT NULL)
```

The idea is to know which IDs have InspectorID against them, then Exclude them from your result with `NOT IN`

Comment: so if inspectors default value is 'none'  and not NULL then i could write

Select * From Alerts
Where AlertId Not In (Select AlertID From Alerts Where InspectorID <> 'none')

Comment: thanks codingbiz, how would i write it if I wanted to select for a specific InspectorID? ie. return the records where the specified InspectorID is not entered against the alertID but dont return the same AlertID if the inspectorsID is against the AlertID in any other record?

Comment: Instead of using NULL, `Not In (Select AlertID From Alerts Where InspectorID = 31030)`

Comment: Perfect thanks, and mild DOH on my part, heavy weekend brain still not working, many thanks!

Comment: Heya, that code works just fine for one inspector, but when I log another inspector in it returns multiple copies of each alert, is there a simple way to solve this? can I solve this with a DISTINCT or similar? or do i need to return the drawing board?

Comment: From the table in the question, alertID can be multiple, so you could get duplicates. If they are exactly the same, use DISTINCT

Comment: it's cool i added "AND dateread IS NULL" to the end of the statement and thats it working perfectly now, many thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM alertsTable
WHERE inspectorID IS NULL
AND alertID NOT IN (SELECT alertID FROM alertsTable where inspectorID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: should have added that inspectorID can never be NULL default value is 'none' would I be better off just working it as a NULL instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From Table
Where alertID Not In 
(Select alertID From Table Where inspectorID != 'none')
```

Comment: great thanks, how would i write it if I wanted to select for a specific InspectorID? ie. return the records where the specified InspectorID is not entered against the alertID but dont return the same AlertID if the inspectorsID is against the AlertID in any other record?

Comment: No problem then you would have to use this after Not In:
(Select alertID From Table Where inspectorID != '31030')